# Boolean from class X doesn't persist between change from view controller of class Y to view controller of class Z

Tags: objective-c, ios

In the class `GHHaiku` I have the `BOOL` property `justComposed`.

In `mySecondViewControllerClass` I have the following methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.ghhaiku)
    {
        self.ghhaiku = [[GHHaiku alloc] init];
    }
    //Lots of other code
}

-(void)saveUserHaiku
{
    //Lots of code
    self.ghhaiku.justComposed=YES;
    NSLog(@"%d",self.ghhaiku.justComposed);
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; //This switches to `myFirstViewController`
}
```

In `myFirstViewController` I have the following methods:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.ghhaiku)
    {
        self.ghhaiku = [[GHHaiku alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%d",self.ghhaiku.justComposed);
    if (self.ghhaiku.justComposedYes==YES)
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        self.displayHaikuTextView.text = [[self.ghhaiku.arrayOfHaiku lastObject] valueForKey:@"quote"];
    }
}
```

The `BOOL` in `saveUserHaiku` in `mySecondViewController` shows 1/yes.  But the Boolean in `viewWillAppear` in `myFirstViewController` shows 0/no.

What am I leaving out?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying to accomplish in the end:

`myFirstViewController` instantiates `GHHaiku` in `viewDidLoad`.  Then it creates `arrayOfHaiku` on that instantiation and loads it with x number of haiku.

The method `saveUserHaiku` in `mySecondViewController` adds a haiku to that array, sets a Boolean `justComposed' to`YES`, and then programmatically switches view controllers back to`myFirstViewController`.

Once we're back in `myFirstViewController`, `viewWillAppear` calls a certain function if `justComposed` in `mySecondViewController` is `YES`.

Both view controllers were created in Interface Builder.

**SECOND EDIT:**  In case it matters, this is a tabbed application.  `saveUserHaiku` changes the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are creating separate instances of ghhaiku - one for each of your two view controllers. If you would like to use the same ghhaiku object between both view controllers (thereby remembering the justComposed boolean), you will need to set the ghhaiku property to the existing object when you create the view controller. Do not alloc/init a new one in viewDidLoad.

For instance, if you were to display mySecondViewControllerClass from myFirstViewController, it might look like the following:

```
mySecondViewControllerClass *secondViewController = [[mySecondViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
secondViewController.ghhaiku = self.ghhaiku; // pass the ghhaiku object to the other view controller
[self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Oh, okay. That explanation is very clear, and I see what my mistake was now. My only issue is that both view controllers were created using Interface Builder, and I don't know how to make it clear that the `GHHaiku` I'm alloc/initing is the one connected to `myFirstViewController`. In other words, the first line in your example code doesn't work for me because the view controller has already been created.  Any thoughts? (I've added code to the question to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.)

Comment: I would try restructuring this to keep your data in a more predictable place (passing data back and forth between two sibling view controllers will get confusing). You could even even use a data store singleton (see Joe Conway's excellent "IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" for a good explanation). Because the view controllers are siblings, they do not have references to each other. Applications tend to follow a hierarchal structure. Because you have two view controllers dealing with the same data, the data should at least be stored outside of those two view controllers.

Comment: Hmm.  There's something I'm not understanding, but I suspect it would be better to ask a new question, so I'll do that.  Thanks for your help--I appreciate it.

Comment: I ended up using a singleton, and that fixed everything.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why should it have other value than NO? You have two different classes. In one of them you set value of a class member to YES. And then in another class you check value of a variable which has the same name, but it's different and you never assign anything to it, and it is NO by default